# Exists a quick way to deserialize a list of objects into a list of fields from that object?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, mapper

I wonder if exists a quick way to deserialize a list of objects into a list of fields from that object?

I have such object:

```
@Data
public class Sample {
    private List<String> ids;
}
```

And I have a json:

```
{
    "ids": [
      {
         "id": "a"
      },
      {
         "id": "b"
      },
      {
         "id": "c"
      }
    ]
}
```

I would like to parse such json object list into string list in "ids" field.
I know that I can do it using StdSerializer abstract class and implement deserialization logic for it but I wonder if exists something more smooth to make it flat.

Comment: change `List<String> ids;` to `List<Sample> ids;`

Comment: I dont want to have List<Sample>, I want to have it flatten as far I can.

Comment: *I want to have it flatten as far I can* That is it if you use the `List<Sample>`. BTW: It is not a good practise to change the question after comments are added

Comment: Ok sorry for that but I understood that sample class was confusing. I just want to convert such json into such string list

Comment: I think then you have to write your own deserializer

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to transform the JSON structure before deserialization.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"ids\": [" +
    "      {" +
    "         \"id\": \"a\"" +
    "      }," +
    "      {" +
    "         \"id\": \"b\"" +
    "      }," +
    "      {" +
    "         \"id\": \"c\"" +
    "      }" +
    "    ]" +
    "}");

// Deserialize to Sample
JsonNode objectNode = josson.getNode("ids.id.toObject('ids')");
Sample sample = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(Sample.class).readValue(objectNode);
System.out.println(sample.ids.toString());

// Or deserialize to List<String> directly
JsonNode arrayNode = josson.getNode("ids.id");
List<String> ids = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(List.class).readValue(arrayNode);
System.out.println(ids.toString());
```

Output

```
[a, b, c]
```